# how to use 2 datatables in same page?

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

how to use datatables in same page, I use template datatables but when I created new one datatables does not work.

here is my code

CSS :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/plugins/datatables/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/plugins/datatables/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/plugins/datatables/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

JavaScript :

```
 <!-- Datatable js -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

Code :
nah, when I create new one with this datatable all function doesn't work..

```
echo "<table id='datatable-buttons' class='table display2 table-striped table-bordered'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>No.</th>";
    echo "<th>Itemset</th>";
    echo "<th>Jumlah</th>";
    echo"</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach ($item_array as $ia_key => $ia_value) 
    {
        //$theitems = explode('|',$ia_key);
        for($x = 0; $x < count($ia_key); $x++) 
        {
            if (($ia_value>=$support))
            {
                $no++;
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> $no </td>";
                echo "<td> $ia_key </td>";
                echo "<td> $ia_value </td>";
                $z++;
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can i see how you're initializing datatables in js ?

Comment: [Docs](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html) are not working?

Comment: you need to make sure that your tables have unique ids

Comment: that link will not work because you set the class name to display2.  DataTables needs the class name "display"

Comment: I take that back, you are using bootstrap

Comment: so in what you have above $(document).ready(function(){$("table.display2").DataTable() ;} )  should be working

Comment: you got a echo "</tr>"; after the tbody tag that should be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Life example in the snipest.

Two Data Tables :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/jszip-3.1.3/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/r-2.1.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/jszip-3.1.3/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/af-2.2.0/b-1.3.1/b-colvis-1.3.1/b-flash-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/cr-1.3.3/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.2.1/r-2.1.1/rg-1.0.0/rr-1.2.0/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.2/datatables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table  id="" class="display table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>john</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table  id="" class="display table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>type</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- Retrieve data -->
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And for more clarification:

https://jsfiddle.net/5qb7optx/2/

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Data table HTML code:

Table 1:

```
<table id="" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th>your table head</th>
       <th>your table head</th>
    </tr>
<tbody>
// Your table body
</tbody>
```

Table 2:

```
<table id="" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th>your table head</th>
       <th>your table head</th>
    </tr>
<tbody>
// Your table body
</tbody>
```

Script for Datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable();
} );
```

By using **`.display`** class you can use it for multiple **`data-tables`**. Just give the same class to all the table.

Here is the helper link on multiple data-tables: [multiple_tables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datatable initializer two times with the ids of your tables like below :

```
  $('#datatable-id1').dataTable(); //replace id with your first table's id
  $('#datatable-id2').dataTable(); //replace id with your second table's id
```

Answer (score -1):

You should write jQuery to initialise DataTable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();//replace id as per your need
    $('#datatable-buttons2').DataTable();//replace id as per your need
});
```

Comment: Except that this results in "Cannot reinitialise DataTable" error and is not allowed. See https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Comment: Never mind, it seems to work if I make sure I call it on a _different_ table element each time :)